# How To make image botton without effect in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i have Imagebotton in content_main.xml with code :

```
<ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/tri1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonTri"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        />
```

and show :
[image]

but i want the imageBotton without box effect, like :
[image]

and than, i will make this imageBotton to go to next layout

how can i do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/tri1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonTri"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your image is bigger than the dimensions provided. Instead of a fixed height and width if you use wrap_content then your whole image will be visible. Something like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/tri1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonTri"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    />
```

In case you want the image to be without box effect, you can try adding an image with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

insted of `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

try using

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

example:

```
 <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonTri"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            />
```